# Save combobox values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a simple userform with combobox values then allows user to add new items and save the items (in the sense the values that you key values into the textbox and both `Combobox1` and `Combobox2` gets updated and remains after closing and re-opening the excel file). Here is my code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.ComboBox2.AddItem Me.TextBox1.Value
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Me.TextBox1.Value
    Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
    MsgBox "Category added to combobox!!"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "Chicken"

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
End Sub
```

'Update the list and save the excel file

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Dim strRowSource As String
Dim lReply As Long, lRows As Long
 If ComboBox1 <> vbNullString Then
 If ComboBox1.ListIndex < 0 Then
 lReply = MsgBox(ComboBox1 & _
 " is not part of the list. Add it", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
 If lReply = vbYes Then
 With ComboBox1
 strRowSource = .RowSource
 lRows = Range(strRowSource).Rows.Count
 Range(strRowSource).Cells(lRows + 1, 1) = ComboBox1
 .RowSource = vbNullString
  .RowSource = Range(strRowSource).Resize(lRows + 1, 1).Address
 End With
 End If
 End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You will have to save the values to a sheet so that when you reopen the file, you can load the items from that

Comment: @SiddharthRout ok but how do you do it?

Comment: If you google `Excel VBA save combobox values to worksheet` you will see lot of examples :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout yeah i tried but most of them didnt update after adding items to combobox and save the combobox values after closing excel. By chance do you happen to know?

Comment: Show me the code where you are updating the worksheet from the combo before you unload the userform.

Comment: @SiddharthRout ok i just listed the code where it shows the combobox will update and save the items after closing excel file somewhere online but it just doesn't work. And according to the user who posted it, it requires me to use rowsource property. How do i do it?

Comment: do not use the `ComboBox1_Exit` event. Use the `UserForm_QueryClose` event. This way you do not have to save the values at every change. Do it in one go before you exit the userform. Also remember to save the workbook so that those vales can be preserved. Also use a textbox and a commandbutton to accept values to add to combobox

Comment: I posted an answer, is if that helps?

Comment: @SiddharthRout i tried to replace combobox1_exit with userform_queryclose but it shows this error message "procedure declaration does not match description of event". Im not sure where did it went wrong...

Comment: You must make a sheet, and then save the value from textbox1 to the sheet if it is not in the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Suggestion**

1. As I suggested in the comments above, do not use the `ComboBox1_Exit` event. Use the `UserForm_QueryClose` event. This way you do not have to save the values at every change. Do it in one go before you exit the userform.
2. Save the workbook so that those values can be preserved.
3. Use a textbox and a commandbutton to accept values to add to combobox.

**Logic**

1. In the `UserForm_Initialize` event, load the combobox from the worksheet.
2. Let the user enter the value in the textbox. Use the commandbutton to save to combobox
3. Save to worksheet in the `UserForm_QueryClose` event. Ensure you clear the relevant column before putting the values back in the column.

[image]

**Sample Code**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

'~~> Load values from the worksheet into the combobox
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    '~~> Set this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    Dim lRow As Long

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                ComboBox1.AddItem .Range("A" & i).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

'~~> Add item to combobox from textbox
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Len(Trim(TextBox1.Text)) <> 0 Then
        ComboBox1.AddItem TextBox1.Text
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing to add"
    End If
End Sub

'~~> Save to worksheet
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    ws.Columns(1).ClearContents

    For i = 0 To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = ComboBox1.List(i)
    Next i

    ThisWorkbook.Save
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

Comment: yup, you save my life... thanks alot mate! Anyways, im still new to excel vba. So can i ask the Thisworkbook.Save is it a save built-in function? So does it means i need not have to save the module/workbook by manual clicking the next time?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Save` will save the workbook which has the above code. It will not ask you to save the workbook again unless there is some change made by you or by something else to that workbook. More about `ThisWorkbook` [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thisworkbook)

Comment: And sorry i couldn't upvote your post but i definitely will once i get enough reputation for me to upvote you

Comment: @Cena - In addition to your comment: it's always possible to accept a helpful answer by ticking the hollow green checkmark just underneath the voting buttons :-)

Comment: @T.M Sorry i missed out. Noted!

Comment: @SiddharthRout ah my bad i thought i can tick both answers lol. I went to tick your answers before i went to tick others too only to realise is can only allow 1 so thats why your answers is being unticked.

Comment: @SiddharthRout hey dude sorry to bother you, is there a way can i link the command button to Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() instead of Public Sub UserForm_Initialize() ? Because when i link with public sub UserForm_Initialize() to command button , the saved values will be duplicated and even i use the duplicate function, it wont be removed automatically unless i create a command button to remove manually

Comment: @SiddharthRout the duplicated function that i used is something like this                                                          
                                                                                       Public Sub Duplicateremove()


Dim rg As Range
Worksheets("Newdevice").Activate

Set rg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

rg.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1

End Sub

Comment: I am out and will look at your comments later tonight

Answer (score 1):

This another method, with assumption that you create a sheet in the worksheet (or you freely to use a new worksheet), and give name for the new sheet with ItemList, here you set A1 as title for example "Category", and begin from A2 below are your item lists, here the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then Exit Sub

    Dim myLastRow As Integer
    myLastRow = Range("ItemList!A:A").SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    'xlCellTypeLastCell is last cell that a range has data (not blank)
    'but if any delete data here, will apply after save the worksheet
    'For example if last is row 3 and col 1, and we delete row 2 and 3,
    'it will remain in row 3 and col 1, until we save or exit the worksheet

    If myLastRow = 0 Then
       ComboBox1.AddItem TextBox1.Text
       'If lastrow is zero, because we will assign range A2 as begin 
       'row of data, so ItemList!A2 will be assigned with TextBox1.text
       'but may be this will not happen, although no Data and A1 is blank
       'it will return 1
       Range("ItemList!A2").Value = TextBox1.Text
       Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim myRange As Range
    'Here we check textbox1.text have been stored or not
    'if not the range is nothing and we add item to combobox
    'add category list in ItemList at row myLastRow + 1
    'myLastRow is the lastRow after last save
    Set myRange = Range("ItemList!A2:A" & myLastRow).Find(TextBox1.Text)
    If myRange Is Nothing Then
        ComboBox1.AddItem TextBox1.Text
        Range("ItemList!A" & myLastRow + 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        MsgBox "Category Added To ComboBox"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ComboBox1.List = Range("ItemList!A2:A" & Range("ItemList!A:A").SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).Value
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: anyways your code works the way i wanted too! Thanks for helping tho..

Comment: Anyways can i clarify what is Range( "ItemList!A2" ) ? Is it referring to the worksheet called ItemList where it starts recording data from cloumn A2 till A column? And also what is the meaning of SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).Value?

Comment: Sorry i have been learning only the really basic stuff so im curious on when and how to apply the following above mentioned..

Comment: I will give explanation about the code, I will update my Answer

Comment: OK, I have finish give explanation and pict